Characters appearing simultaneously in React components
I'm making a game about pokemon in React and there's a component called Announcer which announces what is happening in it.
I made the letters appear one by one just like old games and I wanted that this behavior would happen one message at a time, but React is rendering all messages simultaneously:
https://i.sstatic.net/IYLLcYTW.gif
Here's the code of the Announcer and AnnouncerMessage
import AnnouncerMessage from "./AnnouncerMessage";

const Announcer = ({ messages }) => {
  return (
    <div className="announcer">
      <div className="announcerMessages">
        {messages.map((msg) => (
          <AnnouncerMessage message={msg} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Announcer;


import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const AnnouncerMessage = ({ message }) => {
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState("");

  const index = useRef(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
      setPlaceholder(message.slice(0, index.current));
      index.current++;
    };
    if (index.current <= message.length) {
      setTimeout(tick, 25);
    }
  }, [placeholder]);

  return <p>{placeholder}</p>;
};

export default AnnouncerMessage;



You have each individual AnnouncerMessage managing its own appearance, they don't currently know anything about each other. You will need to either provide a callback when the message has finished appearing (and the parent can then mount the next message) Or the parent will need to control the appearance of all child messages.

What happens in your code essentially is each AnnouncerMessagecomponent starts its “letter-by-letter animation” as soon as it’s rendered.
This happens because each timeout you define in each AnnouncerMessagecomponent is independent from the others.
One way of solving this, is simply to have a “global” counter (in the StackBlitz example below currentMessageIndex) which keeps track of which component is rendering.
Then it’s just a matter of defining a callback function (handleMessageComplete in the example) which increments the global counter.
Additionally, you need to have a dedicated props (isCurrent in the example) to keep track whether the current component is being rendered or it was already rendered before.
We need this to disable the animation on the components already rendered, since React will re-render each child component once a state update happens on the parent component.
Hope this helps, below you can find the StackBlitz repo with the full example.
Announcer
import { useState } from 'react';
import AnnouncerMessage from './AnnouncerMessage';

const Announcer = ({ messages }) => {
  const [currentMessageIndex, setCurrentMessageIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleMessageComplete = () => {
    setCurrentMessageIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex < messages.length - 1 ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="announcer">
      <div className="announcerMessages">
        {messages.slice(0, currentMessageIndex + 1).map((msg, index) => (
          <AnnouncerMessage
            key={index}
            message={msg}
            isCurrent={index === currentMessageIndex}
            onComplete={handleMessageComplete}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Announcer;

AnnouncerMessage
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const AnnouncerMessage = ({ message, isCurrent, onComplete }) => {
  const [displayedText, setDisplayedText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;

    if (isCurrent) {
      let index = 0;

      const tick = () => {
        index++;
        setDisplayedText(message.slice(0, index));
        if (index < message.length) {
          timeoutId = setTimeout(tick, 35);
        } else {
          if (onComplete) {
            onComplete();
          }
        }
      };

      tick();
    } else {
      setDisplayedText(message);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [isCurrent, message, onComplete]);

  return <p>{displayedText}</p>;
};

export default AnnouncerMessage;

StackBlitz Repo
